# Android Studio add jdbc mysql drivers to the flutter project

Tags: php, flutter, android-studio, http, jdbc

Im working on a project and i need to query a database. Im trying to use the jdbc drivers but also by adding the library to the project seems that the java code is not able to find it. I get as exception "classnotfound exception".

[Anroid Studio lib added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOgUK.png)

I'm using flutter also and I don't know if I'm missing any steps to make the java code see the library.

##### Issue solved with http

The drivers were not needed for the project I was working on. So I used php and http to send the queries and get the results.
The php files I created is used are devoid of data checks since the data checks are done in the application.

get.php

```php
<?php
    $conn = null;
    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost:3306;dbname=iumdb", "root", ""); // Database instance
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "{ \"error\": \"Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage() ."\"}";
    }
    $query = $_GET["query"];
    
    $stmt = $conn->prepare( $query ); // Send safe query
    $stmt->execute(); 
    $resultJSON = json_encode($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)); // Convert result to json
    print_r($resultJSON);
?>
```

post.php

```php
<?php
    $conn = null;
    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost:3306;dbname=iumdb", "root", ""); // Database instance
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "{}";
    }
    $query = $_GET["query"];
    
    $stmt = $conn->prepare( $query ); // Send safe query
    if( $stmt->execute() )
    {
        echo "{ \"result\":\"1\"}";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "{ \"result\":\"0\"}";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Don't use JDBC from an Android application, but use a REST webservice to mediate between your application and the database. Not only are JDBC generally not suitable for mobile communication due to their chattiness and security risks, recent versions of a lot of JDBC drivers are more likely to fail to work on Android because they use classes or features not available in Android.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel do you have any guide on that? I never worked on those kind of things. The only other idea i have is make some http page to php file to send query

Comment: Both designing and building a REST service are pretty broad subjects. An example - which demonstrates building one more than designing one is [Building REST services with Spring](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/).